# How to stop React Native re-rendering?

Tags: android, typescript, react-native

I'm still learning to use React Native and runnig into an issue with the stack size being exceeded but I'm unsure why. Looking at other posts I see it must be that the screen is being rerendered too many times and is stuck in a loop but how can I prevent this happening?
**RaceListScreen**

```
export function RandomRaceScreen(this: any, {navigation: navigation}) {
 
  const [raceList, setRaceList] = useState<RaceModel[]>([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchedRaces: RaceModel[] = getCoreRaceList();
    setRaceList(fetchedRaces);
  }, []);

  //number of players must be less than max number of available races

  const racePressed = (raceId: number) => {
    console.log('Displaying info about Race, ', raceId);
    navigation.navigate('RaceLoreListScreen', {raceId: raceId});
  };

  const renderRaces = (item: unknown) => {
    return (
      <RaceCard
        race={item.item}
        onClick={() => {
          racePressed(item.item._groupId);
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

  return (
    <ImageBackground
      source={require('../../assets/space_background_reduced_v1.png')}
      style={globalStyles.background}>
      <FlatList
        data={raceList}
        renderItem={renderRaces}
        sliderWidth={width}
        containerCustomStyle={style.carousel}
        contentContainerCustomStyle={style.card}
        itemWidth={width * 0.8}
        layout="default"
        removeClippedSubviews={false}
      />
    </ImageBackground>
  );
}
```

**getCoreRaceList function:**

```
import {RaceModel} from '../../models/RaceModel';
import races from '../../races/core_races.json';

export function getCoreRaceList(): RaceModel[] {
  let raceList: RaceModel[] = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    raceList.push(
      new RaceModel(races[i], races[i].name, races[i].homeworld, false),
    );
  }

  return raceList;
}
```

Comment: Does this error occur when you hit a specific button or perform some action? Does the error point to a specific line code? Usually this is caused by setting state during render, but the only place you set state is in an effect that should only run when the component mounts. So it doesn't look to me like there's anything wrong with the code you've posted.

Comment: The error happens when loading up this screen. From what you said the raceList does use setState when it is being rendered so I could try working a way around that.

Comment: @AlexWayne the error was happening because I had RaceCard().prototype instead of RaceCard.prototype so it was expecting arguments... Thanks for the help anyway!